# Creating a String ArrayList

Tags: c#-4.0

Can you please tell me how to store an `ArrayList` in session and how to retrieve that `ArrayList` from session?

I am trying to store one `ArrayList` of type `string` and assign values of the same type but it is showing me an error. How do I assign values to the `ArrayList` which is in session?

```
ArrayList arry = (ArrayList)Session["myArr"];
Session["myArr"] = arry;
```

Comment: What are you exactly want to know? Please give us sample code and a better description of your problem!

Comment: Please add the error message you get when adding values to the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
// When retrieving an object from session state, cast it to 
// the appropriate type.
ArrayList stockPicks = (ArrayList)Session["StockPicks"];

// Write the modified stock picks list back to session state.
Session["StockPicks"] = stockPicks;
```

from [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Note that ArrayList is serializable, so you can put it into any session storage

Comment: ya i tried but its shows following error Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'.

Comment: Please, compare what do you put there with what do you get. The key must be exactly the same.